# Why does a python function work in parallel even if it should not?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, multicore, healpy

I am running this code using the *healpy* package. I am not using multiprocessing and I need it to run on a single core. It worked for a certain amount of time, but, when I run it now, the function `healpy.projector.GnomonicProj.projmap` takes all the available cores.

This is the incriminated code block:

```
def Stacking () :

    f = lambda x,y,z: pixelfunc.vec2pix(xsize,x,y,z,nest=False)
    map_array = pixelfunc.ma_to_array(data)
    im = np.zeros((xsize, xsize))
    plt.figure()

    for i in range (nvoids) :
        sys.stdout.write("\r" + str(i+1) + "/" + str(nvoids))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        proj = hp.projector.GnomonicProj(rot=[rav[i],decv[i]], xsize=xsize, reso=2*nRad*rad_deg[i]*60/(xsize))
        im += proj.projmap(map_array, f)

    im/=nvoids
    plt.imshow(im)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.title(title + " (Map)")
    plt.savefig("../Plots/stackedMap_"+name+".png")

    return im
```

Does someone know why this function is running in parallel? And most important, does someone know a way to run it in a single core?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[In this thread](https://github.com/healpy/healpy/issues/558) they recommend to set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` accordingly:

> Worked with:
>
> ```
> import os
> os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
> import healpy as hp
> import numpy as np
> ```
>
> `os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'` have to be done before import numpy and healpy libraries.

As to the why: probably they use some parallelization techniques wrapped within their implementation of the functions you use. According to the name of the variable, I would guess [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) it is.